# Best translation of 四风 (political term)

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is a reasonable translation of [四风](http://paper.people.com.cn/rmrb/html/2021-01/14/nw.D110000renmrb_20210114_1-01.htm) in its political usage? "Four winds" does not seem to fit, neither does "four styles". I do know, however, that this expression refers to formalism, bureaucracy, hedonism, and extravagance.

Comment: Before I saw the words in brackets, I thought 四风 is a word for mahjong game... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**KEY**

> PHR
> "the Four (Evil) Trends" (current term introduced by President Xi Jinping in 2013, used by the PRC government to criticize the harmful practices of xíngshì zhǔyì 形式主義/形式主义 "formalism", guānliáo zhǔyì 官僚主義/官僚主义 "bureaucracy", xiǎnglè zhǔyì 享樂主義/享乐主义 "hedonism" and shēmí 奢靡 "extravagance")